# In App Purchase With daily updates

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In my application I have a page where I want to sell a single article via In app purchase.

The article for the user will be available for the user for only one day.....

and the other day if the new article is available then the user should be directed to buy that other article for that day

Prices will be same for all the articles.

Can anyone suggest me how I can achieve this and how I should register my items into the app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register consumable product to iTunes. Then when user will purchase that product once flag will be TRUE. After finishing of that day of purchase, flag will be again false. So, user need to buy it again.

The other way you can create subscription product in iTunes. So, user need to subscribe everyday or can purchase subscription of 7 days or 14 days. This is normal way in which we are doing news related application for IAP.

Comment: and I need to fetch the data from an external server and need to verify for that user has purchased it or not right?